# Can someone find this hadith in Arabic?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

The scholar Ignaz Goldzeiher quotes a hadith in his work *"Muslim Studies"* vol. 1 on pg. 205.

Someone came into Malik’s auditorium and shows him a manuscript from the folds of his clothes “This is your Muwatta, O Abu Abd Allah, which I have copied. Please grant me your permission (ijaza) to hand it down.” This permission is granted, and when handing down the text you may use the formula: Malik has told me, Malik has reported to me.”[Al-Khatib al-Baghdadi, fol. 84b, ed. Hyderabad, 309]

It is found in the work of Al-Khatib al-Baghdadi, perhaps in his *al-Kifaya fi ma'rifat usul 'ilm al-riwaya*

Comment: This is not a hadith. Al-Khatib al-Baghdadi 's works in Arabic are available online, even digitised, e.g. [here](https://al-maktaba.org/author/246) or [here](https://shamela.ws/index.php/author/246). You could potentially use some tools to search for keywords.

Answer (score 1):

This was reported on the authority of 'Abdullah ibn Wahb one of imam Malik's most knowledgeable students from Egypt -see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13055/1244#p1) in the Book "Al-Kifaya fi 'ilm ar-Riwaya الكفاية في علم الرواية"-:

> أَخْبَرَنَا حَمْزَةُ بْنُ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ طَاهِرٍ، ثنا الْوَلِيدُ بْنُ بَكْرٍ، ثنا أَبُو الْعَبَّاسِ تَمِيمُ بْنُ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ تَمِيمٍ التَّمِيمِيُّ الزَّاهِدُ بِالْقَيْرَوَانِ، ثنا أَبُو الْغُصْنِ يَعِيشُ السُّوسِيُّ إِفْرِيقِيٌّ ثِقَةٌ قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ عَوْنَ بْنَ يُوسُفَ , مُغْرِبِيُّ ثِقَةٌ يَقُولُ: سَمِعْتُ عَبْدَ اللَّهِ بْنَ وَهْبٍ , يَقُولُ: §" كُنْتُ عِنْدَ مَالِكِ بْنِ أَنَسٍ جَالِسًا , فَجَاءَهُ رَجُلٌ قَدْ كَتَبَ الْمُوَطَّأَ يَحْمِلُهُ فِي كِسَائِهِ , فَقَالَ لَهُ: يَا أَبَا عَبْدِ اللَّهِ , هَذَا مُوَطَّؤُكَ قَدْ كَتَبْتُهُ وَقَابَلْتُهُ , فَأَجِزْهُ لِي , فَقَالَ: قَدْ فَعَلْتُ , قَالَ: فَكَيْفَ أَقُولُ أَخْبَرَنَا مَالِكٌ , أَوْ حَدَّثَنَا مَالِكٌ؟ قَالَ لَهُ مَالِكٌ: قُلْ أَيَّهُمَا شِئْتَ "

Here is my own attempt to translate it (including the narrator chain of al-Khateeb al-Baghdadi) -with additional information- take it carefully!:

> We were informed by Hamza ibn Muhammd ibn Tahir, from al-Walid ibn Bakr, from abu al-'Abbas Tamim ibn Muhammad ibn Tamim at-Tamimi az-Zahid in [al-Qyarawan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kairouan), from Abu al-Ghusn Ya'eesh as-Susi  <sup>-from [Sousse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sousse)-</sup> Ifriqi <sup>-from the former [Roman province Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa_(Roman_province))-</sup>  trustworthy said: I've heard 'Awn ibn Yusuf Mughraby trustworthy saying: I've heard ['Abdullah ibn Wahb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Wahb) saying:
> "I was sitting at Malik bin Anas' auditorium, and a man came to him who had written <sup>(copied)</sup> al-Muwatta' carrying it in the fold of his clothes and he said to him, "Oh abu 'Abdullah, this is your Muwatta', I copied <sup>(made copy of)</sup> it and I've double-checked it, grant me your permission (Ijazah) to hand it down. He said: "I did", he asked, How can I express it "Malik informed us <sup>(akhbarana)</sup>"<sup>(literally: We were informed by Malik)</sup>, or "Malik told us <sup>(haddathana)</sup>" <sup>(literally: We were told by Malik)</sup>. Malik said to him, "Say whatever of both you want."

Again this is a report not a hadith by all means as it neither is a report of something the prophet () himself did, said or remained silent off (this is the strict meaning of hadith). Nor a report of the sahabah () nor tabi'yn () (extended meaning of hadith). Imam Malik is a tabi' at-Tabi'yn.